# Unexpected Gateway Response: 515 - Could not decrypt tokenised data (Apple Pay)

Tags: javascript, c#

I followed this tutorial https://developer.globalpay.com/ecommerce/applepay#api

but when there is a token from Apple Pay and submit request transaction to global payment, an error is returned
"Gateway Response: 515 - Could not decrypt tokenized data"

this is a token from Apple pay
"{"version":"EC_v1","data":"tABE3r5bDyQnbs3xbFd1ELqrLkK1Nod2Q+fAo4ir8BbJ2dF2pMxYxiMfO7bM2WzGkDjMbeHQYNgduG2lCRtygN0LrWYm8N1/6PRRzqx3woURKMPbZCTO2BcZe3M+wSe9d5LTTEYW+JpPmkNT9Tdo5O50bP5fDNRLVztfWIvxv1BvLo/byw6GadlkjTfjWKBNz5Wd5+TiqdA/qZQkIxyj+gTSuJ2/bWVdEPuQrMbVe9NwB9+3wf/KYZyRltYn52uI0M+5PNS3UpT4yLKrNrtvNdeiS0mRitZd2elBDzgGcTwRxF+zJzWPMXc6YA1+thynbcs81hDUyFYFpCAPDO1b4ssZOzbQ9ziRRDE9IchwqlOXJ8PjYIUc9Hn8ZLJmvxRQExhiEvBxRo3ZixEfSuCwus6aSdJykXKPH4UUCJIot90=","header":{"publicKeyHash":"zgtVsxrGQ4Sfi7g2xJkLh9vRxnpA5903dDv58HFgHOk=","ephemeralPublicKey":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaQwyNCNknVYQO9wrDiPCB96sSWea1D9NQ6VhHm2rUHlp5Z6BodME/rL6wE1sOe/f8cbXsn8yTOldJIvDx9NrMg==","transactionId":"b9a547ad7aab9a7698d04c9a7f34b3835d1571843642477db1d303b1b5881e17"}}"

post token to global payment and response success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.